# How to update all columns of a R data.table by row?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create a data.table object by taking pieces from other data.tables and combining them. Here's a simple example:

```
a <- data.frame(x=1:30)
b <- data.frame(x=10:39)
c <- data.frame(x=20:49)

d <- data.frame(x=50:79)
e <- data.frame(x=60:89)
f <- data.frame(x=70:99)

DT <- data.table(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 30))
for (i in seq.int(from = 1, to = 30, by = 3)) {
  set(DT,i,.SD,cbind(a[i,],b[i,],c[i,]))
  set(DT,(i+1),.SD,cbind(d[i,],e[i,],f[i,]))
  set(DT,(i+2),.SD,"")
}
```

However this doesn't work. Where did I go wrong? And can anyone recommend a better approach to achieving this kind of an effect? I always feel a little uneasy looping like this in R.

The desired output should be something like this: (showing first few rows)

```
     x  x  x
 1:  1 10 20
 2: 50 60 70
 3:   
 4:  2 11 21
 5: 51 61 71
 6:  
 7:  3 12 22
 8: 52 62 72
 9:         
10:  4 13 23
```

Comment: Could you include what you want your output to look like?  The code you gave above doesn't run for me.

Comment: `1:30` and `10:40` aren't the same length for starters.

Comment: You should include a few more rows in the sample output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yup, done. hope it is clearer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @TimBiegeleisen's answer, which was deleted for some reason:

```
library(data.table)
pt1 <- data.table(a,b,c)
pt2 <- data.table(d,e,f)
out <- rbind(pt1,pt2)
out[c(rbind(matrix(seq(1,nrow(out)),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2),NA))]
```

The row indexing of `out` above is like: `1 31 NA  2 32 NA  3 33 NA`, so it grabs the first row of each set of data and puts them together. `NA` indexing results in all `NA`s for a row.

```
#     x  x  x
# 1:  1 10 20
# 2: 50 60 70
# 3: NA NA NA
# 4:  2 11 21
# 5: 51 61 71
# 6: NA NA NA
# 7:  3 12 22
# 8: 52 62 72
# 9: NA NA NA
#10:  4 13 23
#...
```

Comment: all fantastic answers, but this one seems the most straight forward and gets the job done!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have conflicting classes because you are trying to assign numbers and characters to the same columns. So I will assign `NA` instead of `""`.

That said, here is your solution using `data.table` with some modifications so it works:

```
DT <- data.table(matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 30))
j = 1
cols = names(DT)
for (i in seq.int(from = 1, to = 30, by = 3)) {
  DT[i  , (cols) := .(a[j,], b[j,], c[j,])]
  DT[i+1, (cols) := .(d[j,], e[j,], f[j,])]
  DT[i+2, (cols) := NA]
  j = j + 1
}
DT
    V1 V2 V3
 1:  1 10 20
 2: 50 60 70
 3: NA NA NA
 4:  2 11 21
 5: 51 61 71
 6: NA NA NA
 7:  3 12 22
 8: 52 62 72
 9: NA NA NA
10:  4 13 23
11: 53 63 73
12: NA NA NA
13:  5 14 24
14: 54 64 74
15: NA NA NA
16:  6 15 25
17: 55 65 75
18: NA NA NA
19:  7 16 26
20: 56 66 76
21: NA NA NA
22:  8 17 27
23: 57 67 77
24: NA NA NA
25:  9 18 28
26: 58 68 78
27: NA NA NA
28: 10 19 29
29: 59 69 79
30: NA NA NA
    V1 V2 V3
```

Another solution using `apply` (and not using `data.table`):

```
df <- apply(cbind(a,b,c,d,e,f), 1, function(x) rbind(data.frame(x=x[1], y=x[2], z=x[3]), 
                                               data.frame(x=x[4], y=x[5], z=x[6]), 
                                               data.frame(x=NA, y = NA, z = NA)))
df <- do.call("rbind", df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer carlos! the apply solution is very interesting. Is there any way to make it dynamic? in the data.table, for example, if I didn't know how many columns there are beforehand (a, b, c), is there a way to generalize this code?

Answer (score 2):

May be there is more efficient way of doing this:

```
    rows2<-seq.int(1,30,3)
rows3<-1:10
n2<-length(rows3)
h1<-list(a[rows3,],b[rows3,],c[rows3,])
h2<-list(d[rows3,],e[rows3,],f[rows3,])
h3<-list(rep("",n2),rep("",n2),rep("",n2))

DT <- data.table(matrix(0,ncol = 3, nrow = 30))
for (j in 1:3) {
  set(DT,i=rows2,j=j,value=h1[[j]])
  set(DT,i=rows2+1,j=j,value=h2[[j]])
  set(DT,i=rows2+2,j=j,value=h3[[j]])
}
    DT
    V1 V2 V3
 1:  1 10 20
 2: 50 60 70
 3: NA NA NA
 4:  2 11 21
 5: 51 61 71
 6: NA NA NA
 7:  3 12 22
 8: 52 62 72
 9: NA NA NA
10:  4 13 23
11: 53 63 73
12: NA NA NA
13:  5 14 24
14: 54 64 74
15: NA NA NA
16:  6 15 25
17: 55 65 75
18: NA NA NA
19:  7 16 26
20: 56 66 76
21: NA NA NA
22:  8 17 27
23: 57 67 77
24: NA NA NA
25:  9 18 28
26: 58 68 78
27: NA NA NA
28: 10 19 29
29: 59 69 79
30: NA NA NA
    V1 V2 V3
```

Comment: thanks for this solution! the issue here is that some of the rows I want are skipped due to how the subsetting is done. see the desired result in the question, I updated it recently hoping it's clear. thanks!

Comment: Your `a[4]==4, b[4]=13 and c[4]=23`. How did you get `2,11,21` for these?

Comment: the output should be grouped into rows of 3 in the example, first row being the first row of a,b,c; second row being the first row of d,e,f, and third row being bland; and then, in the second group (starting from the 4th row), the 4th row should be the second row of a,b,c; 5th row should be the second row of d,e,f, and 6th row should be blank